# unable to correctly pass object[] parameter to invoke

Tags: reflection, invoke, asp.net-core-6.0

In .NET Core 6 i succesfully load external DLL and create an instance to call its available methods using Reflection. The problem occurs to correctly pass parameters to Invoke.

Let's say the loaded dll contains this test method:

```
public Json_2fattori Test1_converter(JObject datijson)
{
    Json_2fattori mydati = new Json_2fattori
    {
        fattore1 = datijson["parametro1"].ToObject<double>(),
        fattore2 = datijson["parametro2"].ToObject<double>()
    };
    return mydati;
}
```

and here is the mail code to call it

```
object instanceDLL = Activator.CreateInstance(tipoDLL);
MethodInfo metodoInfo = tipoDLL.GetMethod(metodo);
risultato = metodoInfo.Invoke(instanceDLL, new object[] {myJsonData});
```

where myJsonData is Newtonsoft JObject and it contains original parameters in Json format:

```
{
    "parametro1": "30.0",
    "parametro2": "40.0"
}
```

At runtime the error is :

> Newtonsoft.Json.Jobject cannot be converted to Newtonsoft.Json.Jobject

What is wrong ?

Comment: `Newtonsoft.Json.Jobject cannot be converted to Newtonsoft.Json.Jobject` .Are you sure the types are the same in error message?If so,I think it will not get error.

Answer (score 0):

You have to parse your json to the type of the parameter in your method.

Example:

```
List<object> parameterObjList = new();

ParameterInfo[] parameters = metodoInfo.GetParameters();

Type typeParam = parameters.FirstOrDefault().ParameterType;
            
var bodyObj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(myJsonData, typeParam.GetTypeInfo());
                
parameterObjList.Add(bodyObj);

object objResponse = metodoInfo.Invoke(instanceDLL, parameterObjList.ToArray());
```